# позиционированние иконки перед ссылкой

Tags: html, css, scss, position

Друзья, помогите пожалуйста с позиционированием элемента.
Иконка должна быть перед ссылкой, но не получается спозиционировать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```css
.user-block__left {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;

        ul {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;

          .user-link {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin-right: rem(20px);

            a {
              
              text-decoration: none;
              color: $white;
              font-family: "Helvetica Neue Cyr";
              font-size: rem(14px);
              font-weight: 400;
              line-height: rem(71px);
            }

          }

          .account {
            position: relative;
            a:before {
              position: absolute;
              display: inline-block;
              width: 14px;
              height: 15px;
              background: url("../img/icon/icon-user.png") center no-repeat;
              content: "";
              vertical-align: top;
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

```html
<div class="user-block__left">
            <ul>
              <li class="user-link  account">
                <a class="account-link" href="#">Личный кабинет</a>
              </li>
              <li class="user-link  feedback">
                <a href="#">Обратная связь</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqmGWN

Нужно с `absolute` на `relative` поменять для элемента.

или

задать позицию через `top` и `left`

```
a:before {
        position: relative;
```

или

```
a:before {
        position: absolute;
        left: -14px;
```